# Animating background position of an image based on container size (and photo dimensions)

Tags: javascript, css, animation, background, css-animations

Looking to be pointed in the right direction here.

I have a main div background container that displays a user-uploaded photo as a full-bleed "splash" background of sorts.

But the inherent nature of portrait vs landscape photos (and the fact that this container is viewed "full screen" on mobile and desktop ) makes this difficult to accommodate a wide variety of user photos. (key focal points of a photo are cut off in one device view or another, and a cropping plugin won't really solve for this issue) .

**Here's what I'm trying to achieve:**

If the user photo's dimension proportions are wider than the container, I want to animate the `background-position` to "pan" from left to right.

And if the photo is taller than the container's dimension ratio, "pan" from top to bottom.

This way, any photo uploaded will show the entirety of the photo.  Pointers?